# import C++ module, if fail: import Python version?

Tags: c++, python, module, import, pyd

I have a Python pyd module written in C++. I also have a Python version of the module (which is much slower).
My question is, as I want the program to run on multiple OSs, can I try to import the C++ version in the program and import the slower Python version if that one fails (other OS, architecture)?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can import some thing like this:

```
try:
    import CppModule as Module
except ImportError:
    import PurePythonModule as Module
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can:

```
try:
    import CppModule
except ImportError:
    import PythonModule
```

**Edit:** This answer, while not incorrect, is not really useful. As @Best Games' answer shows, this only really useful if you import the module using a common name.